# what is the subject of last clause?

Tags: subjects, predicate

what is the subject of last clause ?
But shrinking the band gaps of such materials just that little bit further, to the point where a brilliant red is reflected instead, has so far proved beyond their chemical skills.

what is subject of predicate “has” in the las clause?

Comment: is “shrinking the band gaps of such materials” the subject?

Comment: "Shrinking" is the subject.

Comment: Why don't you think of eerything before the verb *has* there  the subject, specifically the -ing clause? That's why the verb is singular.

Answer (score 1):

> *[But shrinking the band gaps of such materials just that little bit*
>   *further, to the point where a brilliant red is reflected instead], has*
>   *so far proved beyond their chemical skills*.

The subject of “has” is the entire sequence “but shrinking the band gaps of such materials just that little bit further, to the point where a brilliant red is reflected instead”.

The PP within the commas is not a supplement, but is sufficiently integrated into the main clause to be analysed as a modifying adjunct of extent.

Answer (score 0):

This is the essential sentence:

> Shrinking [something] has so far proved beyond their chemical skills.

*Shrinking* is the main subject, but if you want the complete subject, it would be:

> shrinking the band gaps of such materials just that little bit further

The text inside the parenthetical pair of commas is just that—parenthetical; it doesn't affect the rest of the sentence.